# Create dynamic variable names based on count result

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am trying to combine a string and number to a dynamiclly generated variable.
Currently tried it this way:

```
const ElementCount = 2;

for (i = 1, i <= ElementCount, i++) {
    let SampleVariable[i] = "test";
}
```

ElementCount will later on be dynamic.

The result of the above function should look like this:

```
SampleVariable1 = "test"
SampleVariable2 = "test"
```

My code seems to be wrong - what do I have to change here?
Solution can be native JS or jQuery as well.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: let in scope is unknown outside.

Comment: `SampleVariable1` is element of array or independent variable?

Comment: @MaheerAli: it's independent

Comment: @NinaScholz: good point! How to make this available outside of this funtion?

Comment: JS doesn't allow you to dynamically determine the name of a variable in the way you appear to be trying. You have to use `if` statements or a `switch`, or most useful, an array or object to hold the different values.

Comment: @RobinZigmond: I have no idea how to do this :-(

Comment: How would you like to work with your `SampleVariable` later on? If just printed or used as JSON the __object-approach__ using dynamically named properties would be suitable. If accessed also dynamically by an index-number the __array-approach__ would be better.

Comment: @hc_dev I had hopes that I can use the variables in a jquery filter function afterwards

Comment: @hc_dev, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748786/use-dynamicly-created-variables-in-jquery-filter-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solution is to use `eval`, but It's nasty code, Avoid using 'eval', just use an `array` or `object`.

1, `eval` solution:

```
const ElementCount = 2;

for (let i = 1; i <= ElementCount; i++) {
    eval("let SampleVariable[" + i + "] = 'test'");
}
```

2, `array` solution:

```
const ElementCount = 2;
let Variables = []
for (let i = 1; i <= ElementCount; i++) {
    Variables["SampleVariable" + i] = "test";
}
```

3, `object` solution:

```
const ElementCount = 2;
let Variables = {}
for (let i = 1; i <= ElementCount; i++) {
    Variables["SampleVariable" + i] = "test";
}
```

Comment: I like the array solution most so far, even though I am not that familiar with the usage.. After the declaration via array, how can get access to e.g. "SampleVariable1", so that I can make usage of its value in progress?

Comment: use `Variables["SampleVariable1"]` to get the value

Comment: Your "array solution" isn't actually using an array, because you're using a string key rather than a numeric index. It's effectively the same as the "object solution" except `Variables` will have access to standard array properties/methods - which won't then work properly because you've not given it any elements at numerically-indexed positions. To truly use an array you have to assign to `Variables[i]` rather than `Variables["SampleVariable" + i]`

Comment: seems to me that the new variables are not usable outside my declaration function.
"SampleVariable1 is not defined"

Comment: Is that for the "eval" solution? (Which I would emphatically *not* recommend, use an array or object instead.) Looks like @tony.ga made a mistake there, one solution would be to replace the `let` with `var`

Comment: @RobinZigmond, no, I tested the array solution.

Comment: @tony.ga: regarding the eval solution, Iam getting an error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Answer (score 4):

There are few mistakes in your code

1. You using comma `,` to separate the statements. You should use semicolon  `;`
2. You are declaring `SampleVariable` inside the for loop so its not avaliable outside. Declare it outside the loop.
3. You shouldn't use independent variable for this purpose as they just differ by 1. You should store them in array and use `SampleVariable[number]` to access them.
4. You should initialize `i = 0` otherwise the first element of `SampleVariable` will be `undefined`

```js
const ElementCount = 2;
let SampleVariable = [];
for (let i = 0; i < ElementCount; i++) {
    SampleVariable[i] = "test";
}
console.log(SampleVariable);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
const ElementCount = 2;

for(i = 1; i <= ElementCount; i++) {
    this['SampleVariable'+i] = "test";
}
SampleVariable1 // "test" (browser)
this.SampleVariable2 // "test"
```

Comment: This works, but I don't like the indirection of using `this` when you know it's referring to the global object. Just use `window['SampleVariable'+i]` if you really want to do it this way.